# mp3 cutter lib in android/java?

Tags: java, android, mp3

For my android app, I am looking for a lib (or the source code) that would allow me to easily cut a mp3 file from the startTime to the endTime I provide.

The declaration of the function I am looking for is something like this:

```
public void mp3Cutter(URL urlSrcMp3File, URL urlResMp3File,Time start,Time Stop)
```

For example, the following call to this function :

```
   mp3Cutter(ladygaga-telephone.mp3,  ladyshort.mp3, 20, 30)
```

would create file ladyshort.mp3 that contains the song from the 20th to the 30th seconds of the original file.

I already tried to look in the source code of existing Mp3 cutter Android App but it’s not easy to find out exactly where and how  the cut is done.

Thanks in advance.

Gilles